# Intensity of particles with zenith angle dependence

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, data

The intensity of particles come to sea level depend to the zenith angle $I=Iv (\cos(z))^n$, where $z$ is the zenith angle and $n$ depend to the particle. 
I know the vertical intensity depend to the energy or momentum of the particle, for exemple, to muons, $n$ is about 2 and vertical intensity is $0.0094\, \mathrm{cm}^{-1}\,\mathrm{s}^{-1}\,\mathrm{sr}^{-1}$ to $>0.35 \mathrm{GeV/c}$. 
I would like to know what is the vertical intensity and the $n$ for electrons, positrons, protons and hadrons.

Comment: Surprisingly this is a hard problem without easy answers. Most of the non-muons you detect at or below the surface are the products of recent inelastic interaction between muons and the air (or anything else: building; hills; the rock above you when you go underground). Even what you have listed here is an empirical rule fitted to data rather than something based on a good understanding of the detailed microscopic processes.

Comment: Right, but is there a list with this data (n and Iv) to electrons, positrons, protons and hadrons? I need to evaluate the background of the cosmic rays. I looked for in the book "Cosmic rays at Earth" but I didn't find the data that I need, mainly vertical intensity at sea level.